# Django multiple upload images doesn't work

Tags: python, django, image

I'm trying to add a multiple upload, but where i upload 2 or more images can be added only one
views with add files:

```
def post_new(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            f = request.FILES['image']
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.image.save(f.name, f)
            post.date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
        return redirect('home:index')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'home/edit_post.html',
                  {'form': form, 'error_message': 'something error message'})
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'home/edit_post.html', {'form': form})
```

and form where i get image form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'text', 'image']
```

and I also tried this:

```
image = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

But it did not help

own model where is the image:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField()
date = models.DateTimeField(editable=True, null=True)
text = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='my-images')
is_super = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

template edit_post:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {% if error_message %}
        <p><strong style="margin-left: 35%; color: red">{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 38.5%">
        <label for="id_title" style="margin-left: 35%">title</label>
        <input style="text-align: center" value="{{ form.title.value }}" class="form-control" placeholder="****" id="id_title" name="title" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 30%">
        <label for="id_text" style="margin-left: 42%">text</label>
        <textarea style="resize: none; width: 500px; height: 250px" placeholder="***" class="form-control" id="id_text" name="text">{{ form.text.value }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 40%">
{{ form.image }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 45.2%; margin-bottom: 20px">edit</button>
</form>
```

I would be happy for any help

Comment: I suggest using Django Batch Uploader: https://github.com/ninapavlich/django-batch-uploader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Post` model a a single image field, so what would you do of other images? If you want zero, one *or more* images per post, you need a distinct `Image` model with a foreign key on `Post`, and then use a [`Formset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/) for the images

Comment: You can send an example?